# How to remove the date and time from comments but keep the name of reviewers in word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I only found solutions to remove both information from the comments: time and name, but not remove one or the other.

Comment: Can someone explain why this is downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word is not made to do this in its settings, but the task can be done with a  bit of work. How much work depends on how many comments you need to deal with. Make sure you have a backup of your document before proceeding.

1. Change the filename extension from .docx to .zip
2. Open this zip file. Within the file, open the folder Word.
3. Extract the Comments.xml file
4. Open the xml file using Notepad or your preferred plain text editor.
5. Search for  `w:date=`
6. For each comment, you'll need to delete w:date= and the date/time information following it. For example, in `<w:comment w:id="0" w:author="Reviewer1" w:date="2017-03-10T20:12:00Z" w:initials="R1">`, you'll need to delete `w:date="2017-03-10T20:12:00Z"`
7. Save the Comments.xml file and replace the zip file's old Comments.xml file with your new file. Make sure you are overwriting the old Comments.xml file. (This is automatic in 7-Zip, the zip program I am using, but I have not used others recently).
8. Change the .zip back to .docx

**Before:**

[image: Comment with date]

**

**After:**

**

[image: Comment without date]